# Powershell get-aduser extract select-object issue with extensionattributes

Tags: powershell

This script works great with the exception of the Home Phone and Mobile Phone.  IF the extensionAttribute is empty then I want the file to have "" for phone#.  Else it would have a phone number preceded with a 1.

What gets returned when it's blank is a "1".   I'm confused why the else part is executing regardless of the extensionattribute being empty or not.

```
Get-ADUser -filter {(enabled -eq $True) -and (extensionAttribute4 -eq "LoadedFromInterface")} -Properties Name, GivenName,SN,Office, Mobile, emailaddress,Department, Title, samaccountname, manager,officephone,homephone,extensionAttribute5,extensionAttribute6 | `
Select-object @{Name='User';Expression={$_."SamAccountName"}},
@{Name='First Name';Expression={$_."GivenName"}},
@{Name='Last Name';Expression={$_."SN"}},
@{Name='Site';Expression={$_."Office"}}, 
@{Name='Work Email';Expression={$_."emailAddress"}},
@{N='Home Email';E={''}}, 
@{Name='Work Phone';Expression={if ($_."officephone" -eq $null){""} else {'1'+ $_."officephone" -replace "\D"}}},  
@{Name='Home Phone';Expression={if ($_."extensionAttribute5" -notlike '*'){""} else {'1'+ $_."extensionAttribute5" -replace "\D"}}}, 
@{Name='Mobile Phone';Expression={if ($_."extensionAttribute6" -notlike '*'){""} else {'1'+ $_."extensionAttribute6" -replace "\D"}}}, 
@{N='Mobile Phone 2';E={''}},
@{Name='Personal Mobile Phone';Expression={''}},
@{Name='Personal Mobile Phone 2';Expression={''}},
@{Name='SMS Phone';Expression={''}},
@{Name='SMS Phone 2';Expression={''}},
@{Name='Personal SMS Phone';Expression={''}},
@{Name='Personal SMS Phone 2';Expression={''}},
@{Name='Pager';Expression={''}},
@{Name='Pager Provider';Expression={''}},
@{Name='Fax';Expression={''}},
@{Name='IVR';Expression={''}}, 
Department, 
@{Name='Job Title';Expression={$_."title"}}, 
@{N='Manager';E={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name}} | `
Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\User_Input.csv
```

Looking for some help spotting the problem.

Comment: I would recommend doing some trial and error with various conditions against 2 accounts where one has the empty attribute and the other has a populated attribute. Once you get the test result you expect, then you can use that.

Comment: @bmickey: I've posted my comment that contained the solution that worked for you as an answer now, so as to highlight a PowerShell-idiomatic solution, but note that Nas' .NET-based solution should work too.

Answer (score 3):

[About Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core) : `*` Matches zero or more characters

```
    PS > $null -like '*'
    True
    PS > 'random text' -like '*'
    True
    PS > '' -like '*'  # empty string
    True
```

[Try this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IsNullOrEmpty_System_String_) `[System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty()`

```
@{Name='Home Phone';Expression={if ([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_."extensionAttribute5")){""} else {'1'+ $_."extensionAttribute5" -replace "\D"}}}, 
@{Name='Mobile Phone';Expression={if ([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_."extensionAttribute6")){""} else {'1'+ $_."extensionAttribute6" -replace "\D"}}},
```

Comment: Tried that and same results, when the extensionattribute is blank I still get a "1" in my file because it's hitting the else.

Comment: Can you execute this and add the output to your post: `Get-ADUser ... | Select-Object -Property extensionAttribute5,extensionAttribute6 | Export-Clixml -Path C:\Temp\ADUser.xml` for such case. Please verify the content doesn't contain any sensitive information before posting

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to test it with something like this:

```
if ($_.extensionAttribute5 -ne ''){ '1'+$_.extensionAttribute5 -replace "\D"}
```

What you've got at the moment is "if this property is not like absolutely anything, anything at all", which can carry unexpected results. Even `$null` is both like anything and nothing, until you ask it if it's like something:

```
PS C:\> $null -like "*"
True

PS C:\> $null -like ""
True

PS C:\> $null -like " "
False
```

Answer (score 0):

[Nas' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52193087/45375) explains the problem with your wildcard use and offers an effective solution.

In short: Since `*` matches *any* sequence of characters *including the empty string*, **`-notlike '*'` is *always* `$False`** (and, conversely, `-like '*'` is always `$True`).

**PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversion logic offers a convenient way to test whether a given strings is either `$null` or empty** - just use the string (variable) as-is in a conditional. Therefore, you can rewrite your statements as follows:

```
# `-not $_.extensionAttribute5` returns $True if $_.extensionAttribute5
# contains $null or the empty string.
if (-not $_.extensionAttribute5) { "" } else { ... }
```

<sup>Note that you only need to *quote* property names if they contain unusual characters, so `$_.extensionAttribute5` is enough - no need for `$_."extensionAttribute5"`.</sup>

Using the .NET framework's `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()` method, as shown in Nas' answer, is also an option, but obviously more cumbersome to type and "noisy".